# Small suffix "1" suddenly appearing in PhpMyAdmin 'id' column

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

In one of my mysql tables (see attached picture), a small "1" has appeared as a suffix next to the "id" in the id column:

[image]

This happened at the same time as when the search results were skipping the very first row.

1. What is the "1"?
2. Would this prevent the first row/result showing and why?
3. What is the fix?

We have tested the same db/table structure on several other servers and we cannot reproduce it however we cannot get rid of the problem on the original hosting server despite a restart and complete dump/re-insert - is it a server specific problem?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's showing that you're using `id` as a sort value in an ORDER BY clause. Probably you clicked on the table header at one point. You can shift-click to select more than one ORDER BY clause.

To remove it, control-click or option-click on the header for `id`.

Hovering over the header row should display a tooltip with some more information about this.